# simple peer webrtc remote video stream not playing

Tags: node.js, html5-video, webrtc, angular7, simple-peer

```
peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
            console.log('peer on stream called');
            console.log(stream);
            this.video = document.getElementById("peerVideo");            
            this.video.srcObject = stream;
            this.video.play();         
          })
          return peer
        }
```

Here I am getting the video stream from a remote machine.
I have logged and checked i am sure that i am getting a remote stream as the stream id at is source is same that i receive here.
`this.video.srcObject = stream;` this line generates a -> error  `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

I tried a lot but don't know how to solve this issue.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did I answer your quetion?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also happen if you have more than one subscribers on the stream event, in that case both subscribers will interfere with play on the same video element and interrupt each other.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `play()` function is asynchronous and is loaded while the play function is running. The solution would be to start it after it is loaded.

Adding the `autoplay` attribute to the video object fixes the problem. And removing the call of `video.play()`.

```
<video src="somefile.mp4" autoplay></video>
```